# Backspin effect in pool game with SceneKit

Tags: scenekit

I would like to create a realistic pool game and to implement at least some basic ball effects. I started from scratch with SceneKit and at this point I'm just studying the proper technology to go with it.SceneKit would be the ideal.
I managed to achieve an acceptable ball effect for sidespin and some sort of forward spin. The one I'm struggle with is backspin. I'm playing around with the position parameter of applyForce method, but it seems that alone will not give me the result I'm looking for. Either I'm missing something (I've got limited knowledge of physics) or SceneKit's physics simulation is just not enough for what I want. Basically I have a sphere of 1.5 radius and I went from -1.5 to 1.5 on Y component for the position vector and the result is either the white ball or the ball I'm hitting jumps when collision occurs.

The first screenshot shows the moment of impact whilst the latter shows after the collision and how it jumps.

[image: Moment of impact]

[image: After impact (ball jumps)]

The two spheres are configured like this

```
    let sphereGeometry = SCNSphere(radius: 1.5)
    sphere1 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere1.position = SCNVector3(x: -15, y: 0, z: 0)
    sphere2 = SCNNode(geometry: sphereGeometry)
    sphere2.position = SCNVector3(x: 15, y: 0, z: 0)
```

And the code that gives me that effect is the following:

```
sphere1.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3Make(350, 0, 0), atPosition:SCNVector3Make(1.5, -0.25, 0), impulse: true)
```

What I'm trying to do in that code is to hit the ball roughly a bit below the center. How I got to -0.25 was to get an angle of 10 degrees and calculate its sin function. Then I multiplied it by sphere radius so I can get a point that lies right on the sphere's surface.

Comment: Please narrow this question down so we can help you. Provide a concise code sample and maybe a couple of screenshots. What did you do? What did you see? Precisely what do you expect instead?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I edited my question.

Answer (score 2):

So I've been reading several papers/chapters about pool physics and I think I found something that at least proves me I can do it with SceneKit. So what I was missing was i. right formulae ii. angular velocity. The physics still need a lot of polish but at least it seems to get roughly the trajectory one would expect when applying these effects. Here's the code in case anyone's interested in:

```
            //Cue strength
            let strength : Float = 1000

            //Cue mass expressed in terms of ball's mass
            let cueMass : Float = self.balls[0].mass * 1.25

            //White ball
            let whiteBall = self.balls[0]

            //The ball we are trying to hit
            let targetBall = self.balls[1]

            //White ball radius
            let ballRadius = whiteBall.radius

            //This should be in the range of {-R, R} where R is the ball radius. It determines how much off the center we would like to hit the ball along the z-axis. Produces left/right spin
            let a : Float = 0

            //This should be in the range of {-R, R} where R is the ball radius. It determines how much off the center we would like to hit the ball along the y-axis. Produces top/back spin
            let b : Float = -ballRadius * 0.7

            //This is calculated based off a and b and it is the position that we will be hitting the ball along the x-axis.
            let c : Float = sqrt(ballRadius * ballRadius - a * a - b * b)

            //This is the angle of the cue expressed in degrees. Values greater than zero will produce jump shots
            let cueAngle : Float = 0

            //Cue angle in radians for math functions
            let cueAngleInRadians : Float = (cueAngle * 3.14) / 180

            let cosAngle = cos(cueAngleInRadians)
            let sinAngle = sin(cueAngleInRadians)

            //Values to calculate the magnitude to be applied given the above variables
            let m0 = a * a
            let m1 = b * b * cosAngle * cosAngle
            let m2 = c * c * sinAngle * sinAngle
            let m3 = 2 * b * c * cosAngle * sinAngle

            let w = (5 / (2 * ballRadius * ballRadius)) * (m0 + m1 + m2 + m3)

            let n = 2 * whiteBall.mass * strength

            let magnitude = n / (1 + whiteBall.mass / cueMass + w)

            //We would like to point to the target ball
            let targetVector = targetBall.position

            //Get the unit vector of our target
            var target = (targetVector - whiteBall.position).normal

            //Multiply our direction by the force's magnitude. Y-axis component reflects the angle of the cue
            target.x *= magnitude
            target.y = (magnitude / whiteBall.mass) * sinAngle
            target.z *= magnitude

            //Apply the impulse at the given position by c, b, a
            whiteBall.physicsBody?.applyForce(target, atPosition: SCNVector3Make(c, b, a), impulse: true)

            //Values to calculate angular force
            let i = ((2 / 5) * whiteBall.mass * ballRadius * ballRadius)
            let wx = a * magnitude * sinAngle
            let wy = -a * magnitude * cosAngle
            let wz = -c * magnitude * sinAngle + b * magnitude * cosAngle
            let wv = SCNVector3Make(wx, wy, wz) * (1 / i)

            //Apply a torque
            whiteBall.physicsBody?.applyTorque(SCNVector4Make(wv.x, wv.y, wv.z, 0.4), impulse: true)
```

Note that values of a, b, c should take into account the target vector's direction.

Comment: How have you created cushions? i have done by SCNBox but responses are not well even in for left and right spins, and cushions are not colliding with balls in high velocity, balls directly pass through inside of them..